# Query IN Clause with parameter

Tags: postgresql, metamug

Here is my query,

```
<Request method="GET">
   <Query>
     select user_id from user
     where user_type in ($userTypes)
   </Query>
</Request>
```

How do I sent multiple values for this parameter $userType in metamug resource file. I'm using a GET request. And my database is postgres.

$userTypes is list of ids. I can pass it as comma separated string "1501,1502,1503" in the request.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show example of `$userType` parameter. If it is some sort of XML you could easily parse it inside Postgresql

Comment: userTypes is list of ids. I can pass it comma seperated string "1501,1502,1503"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
select user_id from user
where user_type in (SELECT unnest(string_to_array($userTypes, ',')));
```

**[DbFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c6b1c808dfafb8934c03a0e4b0eceaa1)**

Answer (score 1):

you can also write it as

```
<Request method="GET">
   <Query>
     select user_id from user 
     where user_type =any(string_to_array($userTypes,',')::int[]);
   </Query>
</Request>
```

I've typecast it as `Integer array` you can use any other datatype as per your need.